# How to avoid redundant double encoding in java.net.URI?

Tags: java, http, uri

I'm writing a convert from URL to URI, for Http method that only takes java.net.URI as parameter.

My implementation is like this:

```
  new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getAuthority(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), null);
```

So it won't break on URL that has space (under the excuse of Malformed URL). However, when encoding the following url:

```
http://www.****.ca/en-ca/Catalog/Gallery.aspx?ID=Mass%20Spectrometry%20[GC/MS%20and%20ICP-MS]&PID=Gas%20Chromatography%20Mass%20Spectrometry%20Consumables
```

it transforms all %20 into %2520, which leads to invalid address.

Is there a way in Java to correctly parse all kinds of URL? Including those with both %20 and spaces? Like a browser or wget command.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own solution, works so far but I don't know if it will break on another weird URI string:

```
  public static URI uri(String s) throws URISyntaxException {
    try {
      return new URI(s);
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      try {
        URL url = new URL(s);
        return new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getAuthority(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), null);
      } catch (MalformedURLException ee) {
        URL url;
        try {
          url = new URL(dummyURL, s);
        } catch (MalformedURLException eee) {
          throw new RuntimeException(eee);
        }
        return new URI(null, null, url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), null); //this will generate a relative URI the string itself is relative
      }
    }
  }
```